# Scenekit using uiview as material texture breaks with autolayout

Tags: autolayout, scenekit, scnmaterial

Using a UIlabel as a diffuse texture works great in Scenekit but when I rotate the device it breaks and the materials go blank. I've tried also adding the labels to a view offscreen but unfortunately the problem persists. Is there a way around that other than unloading the views and reloading them back into every material every time the orientation changes?

Comment: So - you are using UIKit/UILabel on top of scenekit?  That sounds like a UIKit issue and not a scenekit issue.

Comment: Well Apple allow you to set the diffuse contents of a material as a view which is great because when you update the view or a label updates immediately in scenekit. This is great but they don't seem to give you any way to handle rotations. All the views redraw and break the material. The ony way to solve it as far as I can tell is to remove all the uiviews and reload new nes, which is costly.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So assume you dealt with the layout manager and all that already then.  It's in the right spot, but no dice on diffuse.